# Divide OverFlow ASM

Tags: assembly, overflow, calculator, modulo, divide

I'm doing a calculator project for school and all the thing work good , 
but Divide and Mod(%) are giving me a "Divide Overflow" error , how can i fix it?

For the full code : http://pastebin.com/a9cuL0LJ

Divide is line 158

Mod is line 166

Both Num1Int and Num2Int are numbers between 0-255

Or:

```
DivideDo:
push ax
mov ax , word ptr Num1Int
div Num2Int
mov ResultInt , al
pop ax
ret

ModDo:
push ax
mov ax , word ptr Num1Int
div Num2Int
mov ResultInt , ah
pop ax
ret
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious problem is that, while `Num1Int` is 8 bits wide:

```
    Num1Int db ?
```

you treat it as if it were 16 bits wide:

```
    mov ax , word ptr Num1Int
```